# C++ calling std::move on std::unique_ptr without copying

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I am generating an `std::unique_ptr<Device>` in a loop and adding them to an `std::map<size_t, std::unique_ptr<Device>>` which is a member variable.

Header:

```
#include "util.h"
#include <map>
#include <memory>

class Container {
  public:
    explicit Container(char* path);

  private:
    std::map<size_t, std::unique_ptr<Device>> devices_;
}
```

Implementation:

```
Container::Container(char* path) {
  std::vector<char*> files = util::list_files(path);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
    auto device = util::CreateDevice(file); // Returns std::unique_ptr<Device>
    devices_.insert({i, std::move(device)});
  }
}
```

`util.h` is responsible for creating the `unique_ptr<Device>`, and I do not have the source to it, so I cannot change it. When inserting into the map, I need to call `std::move`, otherwise it destructs as soon as it goes out of scope (e.g. next iteration).

This implementation builds fine and works on the Visual Studio 2017 compiler. However, **on Travis-CI with clang, I get the following error**:

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.5.0/../../../../include/c++/5.5.0/ext/new_allocator.h:120:23: error: 
      call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::pair<const unsigned
      long, std::unique_ptr<Device
      std::default_delete<Device> > >'
        { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
                             ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It appears that my implementation is trying to copy the `unique_ptr` when creating the pair to insert into the map. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with subsequent insertions with duplicate keys overwriting previous ones, then:

```
devices_[i] = std::move(device);
```

If not, then:

```
devices_.insert(std::make_pair(i, std::move(device)));
```

The reason why the latter works and the code in the question doesn't is that prior to C++17, the `insert` method had a defective set of overloads, which you can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert):

```
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert( const value_type& value ); // 1

template<class P>
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( P&& value ); // 2
```

Normally, overload #2 should handle the cases where the argument needs to be moved from, but in your case, since you've chosen to pass a braced-init-list, `P` can't be deduced, and #1 wins overload resolution and attempts to copy the argument. By using `std::make_pair`, you can force deduction to succeed for #2, which then wins and does the right thing.

In C++17 this is fixed as overload #3 is added:

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( value_type&& value );
```

which will win overload resolution with the braced-init-list argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct it inplace avoiding creation of any temporaries:

```
devices_.emplace
(
   ::std::piecewise_construct
,  ::std::forward_as_tuple(i)
,  ::std::forward_as_tuple(::std::move(device))
);
```